# Django Model is saved, but returns None

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.5

I have a simple model with a Model Manager:

```
class CompanyReviewManager(models.Manager):
    def get_votes_for_company(self, company):
        try:
            return CompanyReview.objects.filter(user = user).count()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_rating_for_field(self, installer, field):
        try:
            return CompanyReview.objects.filter(user = user).aggregate(Avg(field))
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None

class CompanyReview(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    satisfaction = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank = True, null = True,)
    comments = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True,)

    objects = CompanyReviewManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(InstallerReview, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        return obj
```

**When I now try to save an object in the Django shell, the object will be saved, but nothing will be returned. Why?**

```
In [1]: company_obj = InstallerReview()
In [2]: company_obj.user = CompanyUser.objects.all()[2]
In [3]: obj = company_obj.save()
In [4]: obj
Out[4]: 
In [5]: company_obj
Out[5]: <CompanyReview: AdminCompany>
```

**Why is the 3rd step failing without an error?**

Comment: @Urda I might be missing something here, but I don't see how this is especially 1.5 related.  And why adding "Django" back in the title ?  It is tagged as a Django question already.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because the super class `save` method doesn't return anything. It doesn't need to: `self` is being saved, there's no point returning something else and calling it `obj`.

You could just return `self` from your subclass `save` method, but there's not much point. Generally in Python, if functions change objects in-place, they do not return the changed object: compare with the list `sort()` method.