# id of object is none after save in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-inheritance, multi-table-inheritance

I'm looping through a list of objects and saving.  I need the newly generated id or pointer id right after the save but it is None.

Here is my code:

```
for category in category_list:
      saved_category = category.save()
      print saved_category.parentCategory_ptr_id      
      print saved_category.id
```

This saves my object after the routine is run, but again, does not give me the id at this line.

here is my model:

```
class ParentCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Category(ParentCategory):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

category list was created like so:

```
category_list = []
    for row in value_list:
        category = Category(description=row.description)
        category_list.append(category)


 return category_list
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How was `object_list` created?

Comment: @Alasdair I added the code for object list

Comment: "category" has a lower case "c"… is it a typo?

Comment: @daveoncode yes it was.

Comment: can you show how value_list was created? or give us some context what's the process here? What is returning category_list and where does the first function go? Because frankly, I believe the trouble is you don't save the category objects to begin with, so upon arriving to the second function (with save_category) they stop existing (I might be entirely wrong, I just don't have enough context here)

Comment: @yuvi this is pulled from a CSV file.  The actual category object saves in the database when the entire routine runs, it is just that I cannot get the id at the line above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Model is saved, but returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485651/django-model-is-saved-but-returns-none)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with:

```
saved_category = category.save()
```

It needs to be:

```
category = category.save()
```

The original saved object in the list is the object that contains the id.

Comment: Probably better as just:
category.save()
No need to reassign.

Comment: can you explain more as to  why `saved_category = category.save()` won't work ?

Comment: reassign give me an error: NoneType object (i use django 1.11)

Answer (score 1):

Their is no need of reassign.

```
category.save()
```

When you call save() method the object is saved into database and assign id (primary key) to the object.
[Saving Objects Django Official](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects)

[Other same question asked on Stackoverflow and correct answer by Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485651/django-model-is-saved-but-returns-none)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the object will get saved. Seems that the object you are creating lacks sufficient data to satisfy db constraints. You might have used try-catch somewhere, you would have seen the error. Try adding `blank=True, null=True` to `name` in `ParentCategory` or provide a name while creating the object. I hope this works...