# None type object has no attribute django tenants

Tags: django, django-models

I wanted to add a many to many field to the db, in a django tenants application getting the above error, the code is as follows

```
@login_required()
def create_tenant(request):
    subscription = Subscription.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if subscription.status == "active":
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ClientForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                logo = form.cleaned_data.get('logo')
                brand = form.cleaned_data.get('brand')

                seq_no = list(range(5000, 9000))
                random.shuffle(seq_no)
                seq_no = seq_no.pop()
                schema_name = f'Domain{seq_no}'
                name = f'UID-{seq_no}'
                location = form.cleaned_data.get('location')
                tenant = Client(schema_name=schema_name,
                                name=name,
                                user=request.user,
                                logo=logo,
                                brand=brand,
                                )
                instance = tenant.save()
                for obj in location:
                    print(obj)
                    instance.location.add(obj)
                return redirect('create_domain')
        else:
            form = ClientForm()
        return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return redirect('home')
```

models.py

```
class Client(TenantMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(
        Brand, related_name='gym_client', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )
    location = models.ManyToManyField(
        Location, blank=True
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, related_name='clients', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )
```

error

```
Traceback:

File "/home/biju/Desktop/Dev/multitenant/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/biju/Desktop/Dev/multitenant/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/biju/Desktop/Dev/multitenant/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/biju/Desktop/Dev/multitenant/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/biju/Documents/mtenant/clients/views.py" in create_tenant
  71.                     instance.location.set(obj)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /create/tenant/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'location'
```

I am getting selected locations from form as I can see it printing in terminal, the method I tried, I think usually works for many to many, don't know why it is throwing error. Looking for an advice, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tenant.save()` will always [return `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485651/django-model-is-saved-but-returns-none). You can use the `tenant` object directly instead of `instance`:

```
...
tenant = Client(...)
tenant.save()
for obj in location:
    tenant.location.add(obj)
...
```

or use `.create()` method of the default manager (.objects) that will save the instance for you:

```
tenant = Client.objects.create(...)
for obj in location:
    tenant.location.add(obj)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the first method I tried and it works!